# .NET: Why is this HashSet.Remove() not working?

Tags: .net, hashset

This is the loop where the remove takes place: on each iteration I am checking if memSo is in orgsToRemove, when it is I remove it from user.SecondaryOrgansations. Checking this collection in the debugger however, it does not change after Remove().

Both user.SecondaryOrganisations and orgsToRemove are HashSets.

```
foreach (var memSo in user.SecondaryOrganisations.ToList())
{
     if (orgsToRemove.Any(so => so.Id == memSo.Id))
         user.SecondaryOrganisations.Remove(memSo); //This line is hit, actually returns TRUE, but does nothing
}
```

This is the Equals() and GetHashCode() in the Organisation class

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
        return false;

    var p = (Organisation)obj;
        return (Id == p.Id); // This is hit when Remove is called and is TRUE
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

I just can't work it out.

Comment: Have you explicitly checked the return value of the call to Remove?

Comment: Remove() returns true!

Comment: Can you post a sample program which reproduces the above mentioned issue?

Comment: What's the implementation behind `SecondaryOrganisations`? I.e. if it's a property that always creates a new `HashSet` (populating it from somewhere) then it's not surprising that this code has no (overall) effect.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever has it! I just assumed it was a simple property...assumption is the mother of all errors. Feel free to post as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to sidestep the issue by replacing the for loop with:

```
user.SecondaryOrganizations.RemoveWhere(o=>orgsToRemove.Any(otr=>otr.Id == o.Id));
```

Or

```
user.SecondaryOrganizations.ExceptWith(orgsToRemove);
```

Comment: I tried that second example, the result is the same.